# Mongo updateOne with upsert false not working?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, upsert

I am buidling an application with Kotlin and MongoDb, using KMongo to create, read, update and delete documents. Everything is working fine except for the updateOne method. When trying to update a document with upsert set to false, it still updates the document by adding a new attribute.

This my code:

```
fun updateOneEmployee(id: String, newEmployee: String): UpdateResult {
    var options = UpdateOptions()
    options = options.upsert(false)
    return Collection.updateOne(Employee::id eq id, "{\$set:$newEmployee}", options)
}
```

NewEmployee is a JSON formatted string, this what is passed to the function:

```
{"name":"John"}
```

**So my question is: How do I update a document without upserting?**

Comment: set upsert to `true`

Comment: I'm not familiar with kotlin. But I think you forgot to specify the property which you want to update in the `Collection.updateOne` call: `{ $set: { name: <newValue>}}`

Comment: Upsert is a document-level function, not field-level. If you only want to set the `name` if it already exists, then you'd need to qualify your query to include `name: {$exists: true}`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann the shape of newEmployee value is like this {"name":"John"}, so that is where I specify the property I want to update

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes that was it thanks a lot

Comment: Set upsert to true